# Drupal 7 same token showing twice in token available admin page

Tags: tokens

I have a simple question to understand if I made a mistake (during my migration from Drupal 6 or so ...).

In admin page, when I can use token in fields, in "Browse available tokens." popup I'm seeing same token twice, once with "_", once with "-"

Eg :

```
Nom [current-user:field_last_name]  Texte field.
Nom [current-user:field-last-name]  Field "field_last_name".
```

(here the real field machine name is "`field_last_name`")

[image: example]

Did I miss something ? Tokens are working good but I don't know is this behaviour is normal ?

Regards.

Comment: I *guess* one syntax is Drupal 7 native, and the other is a Drupal 6 way, that was migrated from Drupal 6 to make tags work in content and configuration where you were using them already.

Comment: hum ... I did all migration manually (with Migrate module) and my fields mapping was made to avoid that ... But can you tell me more about that if you know ? In all cases, what _is_ the _good_ Drupal 7 syntax ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior and nothing wrong.

The token with '_' gets generated by 'token' module, and
the second with '-' gets generated by 'Entity API' module (entity tokens).

Any one can be used.